# Understanding the flaw in the query

Tags: query, database-agnostic

Suppose we have a relation

```
Employee={empId,name,department, salary}
```

and we are interested in finding the employees who get more salary than anyone in department 5. Would the following query work?

```
Select e.empId 
from employee e 
where not exists (select * from employee s where s.department = 5 and s.salary >= e.salary)
```

Can this fail in any case? If so how?

Answer (score 3):

It looks fine to me. It correctly avoids listing any employees from department five, even if there are multiple employees with the same highest salary in that department.